# boost asio async_receive buffer size

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

Is there an optimal size for the buffer I pass to `async_receive` or `async_receive_from` for tcp and udp respectively? I was thinking it might be 8192 for tcp and 1472 for udp.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No, you need to understand the throughput requirement for your application and set it appropriately.

Comment: What's the advantage of a large buffer - aren't the sizes I quoted at some socket level? My impression was that ASIO will just fill up my buffer size from multiple receives, but that doesn't actually help/change throughput.

Comment: You can set the socket rx and tx buffers, normally these should be set to a fairly large amount to prevent drops. The size of the buffer you provide to asio is independent of this. Say your app sends a serialized buffer of 2K over UDP, this will be fragmented and sent, if you only provide the 1.5K buffer to asio, you'll only get that much data and you'll have to do another read to receive the rest. As you can see, it's very much app dependent.

Comment: I think your first sentence is maybe what I was looking for. I'm not worried about usage of asio (my wrapper continuously chains async_receive) - I'm worried about performance and optimal memory usage at a socket level. If some internal tcp buffer is 8k then giving asio a 32k buffer would be pointless.

Comment: TBH, you should confirm the default settings first these may already be large enough and you may not need to set them manually in your app.